How to load helper automatically after login (with shield)?
i create my first ci4 project with shield authentification.
So now i'm looking for a way to load helper autmatically after successfull and actually logged-in status of the user.
So normaly i define it in the base-controller
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instance of the main Request object.
     *
     * @var CLIRequest|IncomingRequest
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var list<string>
     */
    protected $helpers = [];
...

But if i do it here, the helpers will always loaded and not only if the user is logges in.
If i try this in the basecontroller,
/**
         * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
         * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
         * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
         *
         * @var list<string>
         */
if (auth()->loggedIn()) 
    {
        // Load helpers for logged-in users
        protected $helpers = ['error','caching','departments','roles','users'];
    }
    else
    {
        protected $helpers = ['error'];
    }

i recieved this error-message "syntax error, unexpected token "if", expecting "function" or "const"" so it think at this place no if-statement will work...
What is the best way to or the right place to load the helper after log in?
